# How to ignore empty array elements with NewtonSoft library

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following code :

```
public City[] Cities { get; set; }
```

In City class, I have two properties

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
```

When a request comes that has this `Cities` field empty I would like to hide this with Newtonsoft.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public City[] Cities { get; set; }
```

But this code I have tried does not work because `Cities` is not null, but empty and the request always has the two properties in this array.

How should I use Newtonsoft in this case? Is there any additional check for the objects here needed?

Comment: Is it empty or do you have two objects in it?

Comment: We can't really answer this question without more context, please supply a [mre].

Comment: It has always those two objects inside, so it is not null. It has those two fields with values “ “ , because they came as empty string in request. I want to hide this array in the response when they came this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) in JSON.NET. I think you are going to ignore this property if it's empty or null so, inside the class contains `Cities` properties add this method:

```
    // ignore a property on a condtion
    public bool ShouldSerializeCities() => Cities != null && Cities.Count > 0;
```

**Update 1:**

As @DavidG mentioned the workaround above won't ignore string fields (Name and Code) if they are null or empty. For making that happen you need to make use of `DefaultValue`:

Define `JsonConvert` settings like this:

```
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
        };
```

Use `DefaultValue` attribute over your desiarred field/properties:

```
public class City
{
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Code
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Serialize your object with the settings you created above:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings) ;
```

For example, if your object looks like this:

```
        var obj = new Foo{
            Cities = new  [] {
                new City() {Name = "A", Code = ""}
                , new City() {Name = "B", Code = "C"}
                , new City(){Name = "", Code = ""}
            }
        };
```

The result will be:

```
{
  "Cities": [
    {
      "Name": "A"
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "Code": "C"
    },
    {}
  ]
}
```

[I created a project on .NET Fiddle to see how it works.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MzoITo)

If you don't like creating new settings, you still can use `ShuldSerializeMemberName` inside your `City` class:

```
public class City
{
   public string Name{get;set;}

   public bool ShouldSerializeName() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name);
}
```

Comment: How will this work for the child cities with blank values? That's what OP wants to exclude.

Comment: @DavidG You are right, I provided another workaround for him/her.